# PowerBi Search function doesn't find text string, but simple "=" does?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm encountering an error when typing out a DAX formula in a new column. The idea is to see if one of multiple criteria are true, and as part of that I am testing which formulas to use.

When trying to see if someone's name appears in a different column, I took two approaches:

**ColumnName = 'Lead'[User.Name] = "John Smith"**

and

**ColumnName = SEARCH("John Smith",'Lead'[User.Name])**

In the first case it correctly finds John Smith. In the second case I get an error: "The search Text provided to function 'SEARCH' could not be found in the given text. This is a problem as I'm hoping to use SEARCH for a partial match on another column.

If I expand the SEARCH formula by including the start position and/or criteria for value not found it doesn't fix the issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, was doing something wrong. Should have used formula:

**ColumnName = SEARCH("John Smith",'Lead'[User.Name],,0)**

Comment: That's quite right -- according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/search-function-dax#parameters, if you do not specify the NotFoundValue (0 in your case), "an error is returned". Since there are apparently entries, where your text is not found, this, therefore, returned a column full of errors.